# Pidgin IRC with ZNC and multiple networks

Tags: irc, pidgin

I am using pidgin and ZNC as an IRC Bouncer. In my ZNC I have configured two networks and I would like to use both with pidgin.

My problem is: I don't know how to choose the network when joining a new channel. I always connects me with the first network, but the second one is never taken.

Any suggestions?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to look at here.  Are you actually connected to the second network?  If not, you need to set your password to "znc user name/znc network name:znc password" in pidgin.  This will connect you to the second sever.

If you are already connected to both, it might be easier to add a channel in the znc web interface, and then do a "/join #foo" in that window in pidgin.

Answer (score 0):

In most clients, you specify which ZNC network to connect to with your ZNC username. For example: `username/network1` and `username/network2`.

In Pidgin, you have to include the ZNC username in the Password field as well. Set your IRC Username to `username/network1` and your IRC Password to `username/network1:password`.

Source: http://wiki.znc.in/Pidgin